# Reduce row scan of update query without using index

Tags: mysql, sql-update, innodb, explain

I am using `MySQL InnoDB` engine. The result of below `explain update` query is

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE H_M_SAMP SET NEW_M_ID=17 WHERE M_ID IN(363)
```

[image: EXPLAIN QUERY RESULT]

Primary key of `H_M_SAMP` table is `H_M_ID`. And there is no foreign key relation.

Is it possible to `reduce number of rows scan` by the update query without using index on M_ID because I have to update the table multiple times?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You want an index on `H_M_SAMP(M_ID)`:

```
create index idx_h_m_sampe_1 on h_m_sampe(m_id);
```

Comment: I have a process which updates H_M_SAMP table many time, will it create the problem?